# PaddleOCR freezes on MacOs Ventura M1

Tags: python, python-3.x, apple-m1, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I have been working on a python script to get text from photos using PaddleOCR. Obviously everything works as expected on Windows x64.
I managed to install paddleocr successfully on my MacBook Pro M1 by manually compiling a few dependencies like MuPdf and lanms-neo however, the script hangs forever on paddleocr trying to process the image, cpu at 100% but nothing happens. I have tested the example above on my windows machine and It runs immediately. Does anybody had a similar experience and know how to make it work on my M1?

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR

ocr = PaddleOCR(lang='en')
lines = ocr.ocr('<path to image>')
text = ''
    for string in lines:
        text += " " + string[1][0].replace(' ', '')
```

I have tried different python versions, 3.9.6 is the only one working with paddleOCR on M1. The installation of paddleocr package by pip3 wasn't straightforward. I had to manually compile the wheels of MuPdf 1.19, lanms-neo and freetype2 before installing their python packages as they were failing on getting some headers even with the python-dev installed. The installation succeeded, no errors and no dependencies missing. the package PaddlePaddle installed without issues with pip3.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an M1 Mac, got it working last week with these versions:

```
pip install paddlepaddle==2.3.2
pip install paddleocr==2.6.1.0
pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64
```

Comment: It worked. I uninstalled the previous version and installed these new ones. In my case I didn't have to specify a specific version for opencv though.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/archive/master.tar.gz
```

source of answer please check [here](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/875)

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer ?

Comment: The comment you cited also includes an important step before :
`brew install mupdf swig`